# Move column to the bottom when reducing screen size

Tags: html, css, css-position

Right now the structure is following:

**Left Column 

Right Column 

Middle Column**

I need to make the next structure:

**Left Column 

Middle Column 

Right Column**

The problem is it should be done without changing the existing structure. I.e. on bigger screens the existing structure is perfect, but starting from @media screen and (max-width: 650px) the structure should change as I described.
I tried to change positioning but it seems it doesnt work properly.
Thank You!

See the code below.

https://jsfiddle.net/vw4b99b1/1/

```css
    div {
      border-radius: 4px;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #header {
      height: 52px;
      width: calc(100% - 16px);
      background-color: #B2D490;
      z-index: 1;
      position: fixed;
      top: 10px;
    }
    h1 {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      padding-left: 25px;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline;
      font-size: 27px;
      line-height: 50px;
    }
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6 {
      padding-left: 10px;
      margin: 10px 0 10px 0px;
      color: #00457D;
    }
    .left {
      width: 300px;
      background-color: #C7E6FF;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 64px;
      margin-right: calc(50% - 450px);
    }
    .middle {
      width: 300px;
      background-color: #DEF0FF;
      margin-top: 64px;
      float: left;
    }
    .right {
      width: 300px;
      background-color: #C7E6FF;
      float: right;
      margin-top: 64px;
    }
    #footer {
      height: 35px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: #57C449;
      clear: both;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    p {
      color: #00579E;
    }
    #footer p {
      color: #FFFFFF;
      text-align: center;
      margin: auto;
      line-height: 35px;
    }
    span {
      color: #D4EBFF;
    }
    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {

      .left {
        width: 60%;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      .middle {
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        clear: both;
      }
      .right {
        width: calc(40% - 10px);
        margin-top: 64px;
      
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

        .left {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 0;
      }
      .middle {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    clear: both;
      }
      
      .right {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 0;

      }
      
    }
```

```html
     <body>
     <div id="header">
         <h1>My <span>Resume</span></h1>
     </div>
     <div class="left">
         <h2>Left Column</h2>
             <ul>
                 <p>Some Text</p>
                 <p>Some Text</p>
             </ul>
     </div>
        <div class="right">
         <h4>Right Column</h4>
             <ul>
                 <p>Some Text</p>
                 <p>Some Text</p>
            </ul>
     </div>
      <div class="middle">
         <h2>Middle Column</h2>
             <ul>
                    <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
                    <li><p>Some Text</p></li>
            </ul>
     </div>
     
     <div style="clear:both; border:none; border-radius: none;"></div>
     <div id="footer">
         <p>© 2015 - the Programmer</p>
     </div>
     </body>
```

Comment: Could you explain a little?
On bigger screens you want cols to be in line left/right/middle and on smaller screens you want from top to bottom: left/right/middle?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. On big screens: left/right/middle on smaller from top to bottom: left/middle/right.

Comment: I tried playing around ( https://jsfiddle.net/ewyq9jko/ ) and I think that the easiest way would be doing it with jquery and absolute positioning.
Get .right and .middle div height with jQuery and position accordingly with those margins.